# What will be expected number of iterations in the following Algorithm?

Tags: random, time-complexity

```
Algorithm RSearch(A,n,k)
//A is list of n distinct unsorted elements
//assuming index starts from 1 and ends at n
// k is element we want to search, assuming there is k at exactly one index
{
    repeat
    {
      i= random(1,n);    // pick random index from 1 to n with equal probability
      if(A[i]==k)
        return true; 
    }  
    until true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer highly depends on `random(1,n)` function. If random function obeys a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) (means probability of each number in the range:[1,n]  is the same as others) then you can consider 2 situations:

1. The first random index is the index of k : It is the best case, So `the complexity of best case is O(1)`
2. You choose n-1 random numbers and try n-1 times and fail! so in your nth try You have the desired index. Notice that if the random function has uniform distribution, probability of getting each element in the set(range) is p=1/n. **So for having a special element you have to try at least 1/p=n times**! This the worst case! So `the complexity of worst case is Omega(n)`

Comment: If random is not uniform, worst case becomes infinitely many iterations.

Comment: @AldenBe you are totally right. As i said, I consider a uniform distribution for random function. This kind of distribution is commonly used in many programming languages such as python,Matlab,... as their default random function.